# Closing fancybox2 modal with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have the following script:

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#close-button').click(function(event) {
        $.fancybox.close(true);
    });
});

</script>
```

I'm trying to have the fancybox2 modal close when a user clicks a custom close button (`forgetit_btn.jpg`).  This is what I have been trying to use:

```
<img id="close-button" src="_assets/img/forgetit_btn.jpg" />
```

MORE INFORMATION:

The following is the code that I use to call fancybox from page1.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : '100%',
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '90%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    scrolling   : 'no'
  });
});
```

The following is the code on page1.php which opens the fancybox:

```
   <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="page2.php">Inactivate My Profile</a>
```

The script at the very top of this post is on page2.php

Comment: Well, what's the problem with the code you're using now? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: It does nothing.   Sorry.  Should have mentioned that.

Comment: try `alert('test')` in your "click" listener and see if it gets alerted

Comment: I added the alert('test') and the popup alert test does come up when I click the button.

Comment: Then something is wrong with `fancybox`. I can't tell what from so little code, I'm going to need a bit more context :)

Comment: I have added more details to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because it is being loaded into an iframe and the $.fancybox that you are calling close on is not the same as the one that is being opened. See this: [HTML iframes and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650409/html-iframes-and-javascript).

You could use the afterShow event in fancybox on the calling page to attach the click event. Add this to your options on page1.php

```
afterShow : function() {
  $('#close-button', $('.fancybox-iframe').contents())
  .click(function(event) {
    $.fancybox.close(true);
  });
}
```

Or if you prefer, in page2.php you would need to access the top level frames scope and get fancybox that way.

```
$(function() {
  $('#close-button').click(function(event) {
    frames.top.$.fancybox.close(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!  The latter way is the way I tried first and it works great!  Thank you for teaching me something!

Comment: From within the `iframe`, you could also use `parent.$.fancybox.close(true);`